# PHP not running a certain SQL query

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

So this is a rather strange one. I'm using AJAX to perform a SQL request when somebody searches for a particular keyword. For some reason, although PHP does not kick up any errors, it does not display any results when running the query below.

```
<?php


$con = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','nbgardens');
if (!$con) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($con));
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"nbgardens");
$min = (isset($_GET['min']) ? $_GET['min'] : null);
$max = (isset($_GET['max']) ? $_GET['max'] : null);
$cat = (isset($_GET['cat']) ? $_GET['cat'] : null);
$items = (isset($_GET['items']) ? $_GET['items'] : null);
$search = (isset($_GET['search']) ? $_GET['search'] : null);
$count = 0;



if($search != ""){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_title LIKE \"%".$search."%\"";

}

else if($cat == "All"){
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_price >= '".$min."' AND product_price<= '".$max."' AND product_type = product_type";
}
else{
    $sql="SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_price >= '".$min."' AND product_price<= '".$max."' AND product_type = '".$cat."'";
}

$result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
if($items > $count){
    echo"<div class='browse-image'>
        <a href='#'>
        <p class='price'>£" . $row['product_price'] . "</p>
        <img src='" . $row['product_image'] . "' width='200px' class='thumb'>
        <figcaption>" . $row['product_title'] . "</figcaption></a></div>";
        $count++;
    }   
}
echo $sql;
mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I am echoing the `$sql` string to make sure that the $search variable actually contains something, and if I copy the string that is echoed into PHPMyAdmin, it runs perfectly and returns as it should. This code works for displaying and updating the results in the `else if` and `else` statements, but just does nothing when it matches the `if(search != "")` statement.

EDIT: This is the string that is produced when I search "First Gnome".
[image: $sql]
I can copy this text exactly as-is, and run it in PHPMyAdmin and it will return the result, as shown below:

[image: PHPMyAdmin]

Comment: You are wide open for SQL injection. Since you're using mysqli, look into prepared statements and parameter binding.

Comment: try to echo anything inside `if(search != "")` to check if it matches your condition or not

Comment: @aynber This is purely for developmental purposes and is only locally hosted, not something for a real environment. Not a helpful comment.

Comment: I have done so @odai, if it does not match the condition it will set the $sql variable to one of the other options so I don't think this is the issue. Plus I can print the $sql variable and it looks exactly as it should.

Comment: @SixTailedFox Actually, it's good practice all around. And it would eliminate any quoting issues that might crop up.

Comment: check the html source code of your rendered page, maybe css for browse-image is  hidden. Even if you cannot see it, it might be there. Spooky.

Comment: Definitely not there. browse-image is visible when I search using the other SQL queries, just not this.

Comment: I hate when people say *"I'm not that far along..."* or *"This site will not be public..."* or *"It's only for school, so security doesn't matter..."*. If teachers and professors are not talking about security from day one, they're doing it wrong. Challenge them. They're teaching sloppy and dangerous coding practices which students will have to unlearn later. I also hate it when folks say, *"I'll add security later..."* or *"Security isn't important now..."* or *"Ignore the security risk..."*. If you don't have time to do it right the first time, when will you find the time to add it later?

Comment: Have you checked your error logs? You're making an assumption the query is working.
Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Comment: I understand your point, however I feel that if I cannot get anything to display to begin with, adding security probably isn't going to be overly advantageous.. I have added the error reporting and it isn't throwing anything up?

Comment: Are you sure `$search != ''`? Comment out the if statement bits and just run that alone to see if you get results.

Comment: I did question that, so I tried commenting all statements out and set this to be the only query, however it still produces nothing.

Comment: Add `or die(mysqli_error($con))` to your result line

Comment: You need to remove `mysqli_select_db()`. It is only for *after* the initial database choice.

Comment: I have done both of those things and still no luck. Also just updated to the latest XAMPP but this did not help.

Comment: Then I am unsure how we can help you from here. Without being about to see your logs or test your system ourselves we cannot begin to determine what may be wrong with the code you have provided.